# Fridge water dispenser line keeps freezing and not dispense water unless I dump the ice bucket

Tags: water, refrigerator, freezing, ice-maker

I have a Whirlpool side-by-side which has the ice bucket on the freezer door, right above the ice and water dispenser. Until recently, there was a person in my house who used a lot of ice, and the water dispenser never had a problem. This person decided not to like ice anymore (?!), so the ice bucket was always full, and the water dispenser would randomly stop working.

After some detective work, I figured out the water line was frozen, and the only way to get it to unfreeze was to dump all the ice, so that the ice maker would try to pump water again, which helps defrost the water line. So now every night I have to go dump the ice bucket. Whenever I forget to do that, the water dispenser would stop working the day after.

Any advice on how to fix this permanently?

Comment: If your fridge has an energy saving feature that's turned on, try turning it off.  Typically theres a heater or two to minimize door and gasket condensation.

Comment: Finally got around to getting someone to look at it. They said there is indeed a heating element somewhere in the door and it's probably broken. Ordering a replacement now, will update when it's all done.

Comment: Any update, @Zoomzoom?